# Trying to make it so if the 3rd option on the dropdown is chosen, then the text boxes will disable and a new box will appear

Tags: javascript, html

I have three options on the drop down when the third option is selected i want the two boxes to be hidden and disabled then the hidden box to appear. Any help is appreciated. I have no class ID for the drop down.

```js
function changetextbox()
    if (document.getElementsByName("customerType")[0].options[2].selected = true;) {
        document.getElementById("retCustDetails").disable= true;
        document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("retCustDetails").disable= false ;
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="makeBooking">
    <h2>Make booking</h2>
    Your details
    Customer Type: <select name="customerType">
        <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
        <option value="ret">Customer</option>
        <option value="trd">Trade</option>
</select>

<div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
    Forename <input type="text" name="forename">
    Surname <input type="text" name="surname">
</div>
<div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
    Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: @Yousername I have edited my post at the bottom

Comment: In your if, you wrote `= true;`. Did you mean `=== true`?

Comment: @Yousername I've changed that, but it still does not work sadly

Comment: `retCustDetails` is a div so it doesn't have a disable property. You also never call on your created function.

Comment: @Yousername Ah i see, is there anyway to make it hidden instead?

Comment: I'll try posting an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frist add an oninput event to the `select` tag and an ID to it so you can access it easier like this:

```
<select id="customerType" name="customerType" oninput="checkValue()">
```

Then make this script that will get the value of the `select` element and then check which elements it needs to show or hide:

```
function checkValue() {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById('customerType').value;

    var retEle = document.getElementById("retCustDetails");
    var trdEle = document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails");

    if (selectedValue == 'trd') {
       retEle.style.visibility = 'hidden';
       trdEle.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
       retEle.style.visibility = 'visible';
       trdEle.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

You should get this once your done:

```js
function checkValue() {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById('customerType').value;

    var retEle = document.getElementById('retCustDetails');
    var trdEle = document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails');

    if (selectedValue == 'trd') {
       retEle.style.visibility = 'hidden';
       trdEle.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
       retEle.style.visibility = 'visible';
       trdEle.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="makeBooking">
    <h2>Make booking</h2>
    Your details
    Customer Type: 
    <select id="customerType" name="customerType" oninput="checkValue()">
        <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
        <option value="ret">Customer</option>
        <option value="trd">Trade</option>
    </select>

    <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
        Forename <input type="text" name="forename">
        Surname <input type="text" name="surname">
    </div>
    <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
        Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName">
    </div>
</section>
```

### Edit

Since your not allowed to change the HTML, try this script here instead:

```
document.getElementsByName('customerType')[0].oninput = function() {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementsByName('customerType')[0].value;

    var retEle = document.getElementById('retCustDetails');
    var trdEle = document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails');

    if (selectedValue == 'trd') {
       retEle.style.visibility = 'hidden';
       trdEle.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
       retEle.style.visibility = 'visible';
       trdEle.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

So you'll end up with:

```js
document.getElementsByName('customerType')[0].oninput = function() {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementsByName('customerType')[0].value;

    var retEle = document.getElementById('retCustDetails');
    var trdEle = document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails');

    if (selectedValue == 'trd') {
       retEle.style.visibility = 'hidden';
       trdEle.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
       retEle.style.visibility = 'visible';
       trdEle.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="makeBooking">
    <h2>Make booking</h2>
    Your details
    Customer Type: <select name="customerType">
        <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
        <option value="ret">Customer</option>
        <option value="trd">Trade</option>
    </select>

    <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
        Forename <input type="text" name="forename">
        Surname <input type="text" name="surname">
    </div>
    <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
        Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName">
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Sadly I cannot add any code to the HTML portion such as oninput="checkValue()

Comment: Perfect that works amazingly thank you very much jack.

Comment: Sure, if you have any more questions, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Divs don't have a "disabled." So, you'll have to disable each child of the div.

```js
document.getElementsByName('customerType')[0].onchange = 
function changetextbox() {
  var inp = document.getElementById("retCustDetails").childNodes;
  if (document.getElementsByName("customerType")[0].options[2].selected === true) {
    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
      inp[i].disabled = true;
    }  
    document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails").style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
      inp[i].disabled = false;
    }  
    document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="makeBooking">
  <h2>Make booking</h2>
  Your details
  Customer Type:
  <select name="customerType">
    <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
    <option value="ret">Customer</option>
    <option value="trd">Trade</option>
  </select>

  <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
    Forename <input type="text" name="forename"> Surname <input type="text" name="surname">
  </div>
  <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
    Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName">
  </div>
```

Comment: Sadly I am not allowed to edit or add anything to the HTML. I can only use the HTML that is present.

Comment: I haven't edited it? What has changed? oh... ok ill edit mine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that? I'm not exactly sure if that is what you want to have.

```js
$('#tradeCustDetails').css({ 'display': 'none' });
  $(document).on('change','select',function(){
   var selectvalue = $('select').val();
   if(selectvalue == 'trd'){
    $('#retCustDetails').css({ 'display': 'none' });
    $('#tradeCustDetails').css({ 'display': 'block' });
    $('#tradeCustDetails').css({ 'visibility': 'visible' });
   } else {
    $('#retCustDetails').css({ 'display': 'block' });
    $('#tradeCustDetails').css({ 'display': 'none' });
    $('#tradeCustDetails').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden' });
   }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <section id="makeBooking">
        <h2>Make booking</h2>
        Your details
        Customer Type: <select name="customerType">
            <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
            <option value="ret">Customer</option>
            <option value="trd">Trade</option>
        </select>

        <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
            Forename <input type="text" name="forename">
            Surname <input type="text" name="surname">
        </div>
        <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
            Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName">
        </div>
```

Comment: I can only use Javascript not Jquery sadly.

Comment: What about adding the pure jQuery source code to your JS file? It's not even 90KB.